# Piping in Python 2.6 to a file with while loop

Tags: python

I'm completely new to Python piping but I think it's the answer to my problem. I've got a file cleverbot.py that takes endless input from raw_input and prints out the results to the command line. This is done while staying in a while loop the whole time, and when you say "bye" the script exits.

Now, can someone give me an example where I can pipe inputs to this script and then receive the output, without it ending the loop? The loop acts as a session and it's important that the script continues to run constantly inside this while loop while being able to have inputs piped to it.

Here is a snippet of the code. For anyone that wants to get the full thing its the pycleverbot library.

```
def main():
    import sys
    cb = Session()

    q = ''
    while q != 'bye':
            try:
                    q = raw_input("> ")
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    print
                    sys.exit()
            print cb.Ask(q)
```

The cb = Session() can't be recreated at all after it's first made. That's why the while loop is in place. I lack the necessary logic to see a way of not using a while loop.

Hope this makes sense, thanks.

Comment: why not use sys.stdin.  When you say "where I can pipe inputs" is inputs (plural) indicating multiple possible files during one "session". if so that is an entirely different class of question/answers.

Comment: Yes it's plural. Basically multiple lines of text as the input, multiple lines of text as the output. The hardest is keeping the conversation intact, which is this case the "session". I'll update the question with a snippet code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to not use a while loop in the first place.

```
for line in sys.stdin:
  if line.lower().strip() == 'bye':
    break
  sys.stdout.write(do_something(line))
  sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Thanks, I added a code snippet to the post perhaps it would explain how it works more. Since I lack the necessary logic to see how it would work without a while loop.